# mongoDB insert and process.nextTick

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a list of 50k entries that I am entering into my db.

```
var tickets = [new Ticket(), new Ticket(), ...]; // 50k of them
tickets.forEach(function (t, ind){
    console.log(ind+1 + '/' + tickets.length);
    Ticket.findOneAndUpdate({id: t.id}, t, {upsert: true}, function (err, doc){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('inserted');
        }
    });
});
```

Instead of the expected interleaving of

```
1 / 50000
           inserted
2 / 50000
           inserted
```

I am getting all of the indices followed by all of the inserted confirmations

```
1 / 50000
2 / 50000
...
50000 / 50000
inserted
inserted
...
inserted
```

I think something is happening with process.nextTick. There is a significant slow down after a few thousand records.

Does anyone know how to get the efficient interleaving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Instead of the expected interleaving

That would be the expected behavior only for synchronous I/O.

Remember that these operations are all *asynchronous*, which is a key idea of node.js. What the code does is this:

```
for each item in the list, 
  'start a function' // <-- this will immediately look at the next item
    output a number (happens immediately)
      do some long-running operation over the network with connection pooling 
      and batching. When done, 
         call a callback that says 'inserted'
```

Now the code will launch a ton of those functions that, in turn, send requests to the database. All that will happen long before the first request has even *reached* the database. It is likely that the OS doesn't even bother to actually send the first TCP packets before you're at, say ticket 5 or 10 or so.

To answer the question from your comment: No, the requests will be sent out relatively soon (that is up to the OS), but the *results* won't reach your single-threaded javascript code before your loop hasn't finished queuing up the 50k entries. This is because the `forEach` is your currently running piece of code, and all events that come in while it's running will be processed only after it's finished - you'll observe the same if you use `setTimeout(function() { console.log("inserted... not") }, 0)` instead of the actual DB call, because `setTimeout` is also an async event.

To make your code fully async, your data source should be some kind of (async) iterator that provides data, instead of a huge array of items.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. The database is local so I expect it to update relatively quickly. The operation is still running and when I check the db using a different terminal the collection is still empty. Are you saying that the actual inserting is deferred until everything is queued?

Answer (score 1):

You are running into the wonders of node's asynchronicity. It's sending the upsert requests off into the ether, then continuing on to the next record without waiting for a response. Does it matter, as it's just an informational message that is not in sync with the upsert. You might want to use the Async library to flip through your array, if you need to make sure they are done in order.

Comment: Order doesn't matter I'll look into an asynchronous solution. Thanks! I was afraid it queues it up and forgets it.

Comment: Nope, won't do that. Your solution is probably okay. But Async is a lovely library that eases much of the pain of node. Look for Async caolan, you'll find it.